# Set a string input to accept an answer from an array of acceptable answers (Python 3.8.4)

Tags: python, arrays, string, input

```
#important variables
thePhrase = input("What phrase will we be dealing with today?")
menuInput = input("What would you like to do with the phrase?") 

#search query tables
phraseLenArray = ["LEN", "LENGTH", "TEXT LENGTH", "PHRASE LENGTH", "STRING LENGTH", "LENGTH OF THE TEXT", "LENGTH OF THE PHRASE", "LENGTH OF THE STRING", "HOW LONG IS THE TEXT", "HOW LONG IS THE PHRASE", "HOW LONG IS THE STRING"]
phraseFilterArray = ["FILTER", "FILTER THE TEXT", "FILTER THE PHRASE", "FILTER THE STRING",]


if menuInput == phraseLenArray.lower():
    phraseLen()
elif menuInput == phraseFilterArray.lower():
        phraseFilter()


def phraseLen():
    print(len(thePhrase))

def phraseFilter():
    filterTxt = input("What are you trying to filter for?")
    if filterTxt in thePhrase:
        print("The filtered text,", filterTxt, "was found in the text.")
    else:
        print("The filtered text was not found in the text")
```

I am trying to make the input "menuInput" accept answers from the arrays, being case insensitive.
When I run this code the error message is,
"Line 10: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'"

Comment: You are trying to change the case of a list. This will raise an error. You need to iterate over the list like ```phraseLenArray=[str(x).lower() for x in phraseLenArray]```. Just curious, why do you want to convert the words in the to a lower case? Since, it has a upper case phrases, you can convert your input into uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

`phraseLenArray` is a list. When you try to convert a list to upper case, it will raise an error. There are a few changes I made to your code.

First, always define the functions before you call them. Here, you are following procedural programming and python is reading from top to bottom. When it comes across a function which was defined *after* calling your function, it will raise an error.

Second, you can just convert the input into an uppercase letter using `.upper()`.

Here is the code;

```
thePhrase = input("What phrase will we be dealing with today?")
menuInput = input("What would you like to do with the phrase?") 

#search query tables
phraseLenArray = ["LEN", "LENGTH", "TEXT LENGTH", "PHRASE LENGTH", "STRING LENGTH", "LENGTH OF THE TEXT", "LENGTH OF THE PHRASE", "LENGTH OF THE STRING", "HOW LONG IS THE TEXT", "HOW LONG IS THE PHRASE", "HOW LONG IS THE STRING"]
phraseFilterArray = ["FILTER", "FILTER THE TEXT", "FILTER THE PHRASE", "FILTER THE STRING",]
def phraseLen():
    print(len(thePhrase))

def phraseFilter():
    filterTxt = input("What are you trying to filter for?")
    if filterTxt in thePhrase:
        print("The filtered text,", filterTxt, "was found in the text.")
    else:
        print("The filtered text was not found in the text")

if menuInput.upper() in phraseLenArray:
    phraseLen()
elif menuInput.upper() in phraseFilterArray:
    phraseFilter()
```

Comment: I was trying to make it accept the answers in the lists, disregarding whether it was capitalized or not.

Comment: @Koboman, That would add case sensitivity

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, also, if you don't mind. Could you explain how/why the .upper condition makes text case insensitive while the .lower does not?

Comment: No, ```.upper()``` also remove case sensitivity. It converts the word into uppercase. You said you were trying to make it accept the answers in the lists, disregarding whether it was capitalized or not. The problem is python is case sensitive and it checks if the case matches to. @Koboman

Comment: I do suppose your solution works quite well. Thank you! For future reference, how would I make it to where any inputs from the list of accepted inputs, are not case sensitive, example
Accepted: yes, ya, yea, yup
Input: yEs, yAm YEam YUp (how to accept these potential inputs)
Tl;Dr, how would I make it to where Python accepts the answers from the list, accepting them only if the exact same letters are entered, whether or not they are capitalized or lowercase

Comment: You can add the accepted inputs in lowercase in a list and then when you compare those, you can add ```.lower()``` to the variable taking the input. @Koboman

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the error, `phraseLenArray` is a list and so does not have a `lower` method. You might try uppercasing menuInput:

```py
if menuInput.upper() in phraseLenArray:
```

or using a map and lambda:

```py
if menuInput in map(lambda s: s.lower(), phraseLenArray):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for phraseLen in phraseLenArray:
    if phraseLen == menuInput:
        phraseLen()
```

The function `lower()` is an attribute of `string` instead of `list`, so you need to use a for-loop (or something else) to get the items inside the `list` and compare them with your `menuInput`.